# Whats the main differences between Mapreduce and apache's hama?

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hama, bulk-synchronous-parallel

Hi I am finding it difficult comparing mapreduce with hama, I understand that hama uses this bulk synchronous parallel model and that the worker nodes can communicate with one another whereas in apache's hadoop the worker nodes only communicate to the namenode correct? If so I don't understand the benefits hama would have over a standard mapreduce in hadoop thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you go through this PDF [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.2081v2.pdf)

This explains the difference between MapReduce and BSP(Apache Hama offers  Bulk Synchronous Parallel computing engine).

Answer (score -1):

`MapReduce`framework has been used to solve a number of non-trivial problems in academia. Putting MapReduce on strong theoretical foundations is crucial in understanding its capabilities. T
while`Hama`use BSP model of computation, underlining the relevance of BSP to modern parallel algorithm design and deﬁning a subclass of BSP algorithms that can be eﬃciently implemented in MapReduce.